# Only append rows from matching columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried different things using merge/concat/append, but I don't get the result I want.

Table1

| id | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | hello |
| 2 | Y | hello |
| 3 | Z | hello |
| 4 | W | hello |

Table2

| id | colB | colD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | L | bye |
| 13 | M | bye |
| 14 | N | bye |
| 15 | O | bye |

Admired result after append:

| id | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | hello |
| 2 | Y | hello |
| 3 | Z | hello |
| 4 | W | hello |
| 12 | L | NaN |
| 13 | M | NaN |
| 14 | N | NaN |
| 15 | O | NaN |

I want to expand `Table1` with the rows from `Table2`, but without also taking the colD-column from `Table2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can first concat and then select columns from `df1` (*Table1*)

```
new_df = pd.concat((df1,df2),sort=False).loc[:,df1.columns]
```

Or with `reindex`:

```
new_df = pd.concat((df1,df2),sort=False).reindex(columns=df1.columns)
```

Comment: thanks, that was the generic solution I was looking for. Can you recommend which option is the "cleaner"/"better" one? Both are working for me, I'm just curious which would be best practice.

Comment: @Ricardo definitely `loc` but you can `%timeit` to see. I think `loc` is best fit here.

Comment: @Ricardo on the cleaner , I will let you decide ;) since cleaner is quite subjective

Comment: yeah you are right, but I used loc before so your answer fits me :b

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate two dataframes and drop a column you do not need:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop(df2.columns.difference(df1.columns), axis=1)\
                              .reset_index(drop=True)

print(result)

    id  colB     colC
0    1     X    hello
1    2     Y    hello
2    3     Z    hello
3    4     W    hello
4   12     L      NaN
5   13     M      NaN
6   14     N      NaN
7   15     O      NaN
```

We dropped all columns which are different, without specifying a certain name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pd.concat([df, df1]).drop(columns='colD')
```

Output:

```
    id  colB    colC
0   1   X   hello
1   2   Y   hello
2   3   Z   hello
3   4   W   hello
0   12  L   NaN
1   13  M   NaN
2   14  N   NaN
3   15  O   NaN
```